# Matching string columns against complex string patterns within a SQL Server view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, create-view

I have been tasked with creating a SQL Server 2016 view that will display current database names in my development environment that do not conform to any of the following three naming conventions.

The three valid naming conventions I've been given

- 'XXX_YYY_DEV'
- 'XXX_YYY_DEV-nnn.nnn.nnn'
- 'XXX_YYY_DEV-nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn'

where `XXX` is a variable length string at least 1 alphanumeric character long, `YYY` is another variable length string at least 1 alphanumeric character long and each occurrence of `nnn` is a variable length numeric value (minimum value='0') that can be the same as any of the other nnn's.

Examples:

Database names

- 'Dinky_cu5tomer_DEV'
- '5aussage_Orders_DEV-12.3.0'
- 'TExt1_text2_DEV-999.57.1.57'

conform to the standards so are to be excluded from the view.

Database names

- '_cu5tomer_DV'
- '5aussage_Orders_Now_DEV-12.3.0'
- 'TExt1_text2_DEV-999.99a.1.57'

don't conform to the standards so are to be included from the view.

I've tried separating out the component parts but the numeric part is really stumping me.

Here is as far as I got with the Numeric bits commented out.

```
CREATE View vw_NonStandardDatabaseNames 
AS
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        X.DBRealName AS 'Non-Standard Name',*
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
             db.name AS [DBRealName],

             -- Client
             (CASE 
                 WHEN PATINDEX ('%[_]%', db.name) > 1 
                    THEN SUBSTRING(db.name,1,PATINDEX ('%[_]%', db.name)-1)
                    ELSE ''
              END) AS [Client],

             -- First Underscore
             PATINDEX ('%[_]%', db.name) AS [Pos_1], 
             (CASE 
                 WHEN PATINDEX ('%[_]%', db.name) > 0 
                    THEN '_'
                    ELSE ''
              END) AS [US_1],
             (CASE 
                 WHEN PATINDEX ('%[_]DEV%', db.name) > 0 
                    THEN '_'
                    ELSE ''
              END) AS [US_2], 

             -- Database Name
             (CASE 
                 WHEN PATINDEX ('%[_]%', db.name) <= 1 
                    THEN '' -- No Underscore 1
                 WHEN PATINDEX ('%[_]DEV%', db.name) <= 3  
                    THEN '' -- No Client
                 WHEN PATINDEX ('%[_]%', db.name) = PATINDEX  ('%[_]DEV%', db.name) 
                    THEN '' -- No first underscore only second one + System Name.
                 WHEN PATINDEX ('%[_]%', db.name)+1 = PATINDEX ('%[_]DEV%', db.name) 
                    THEN '' -- First underscore but no DB Name then second underscore + System Name.
                 WHEN PATINDEX ('%[_]%', db.name) > 1 
                      AND PATINDEX ('%[_]DEV%', db.name) > 3 
                    THEN SUBSTRING(db.name, PATINDEX ('%[_]%', db.name)+1,(PATINDEX('%[_]DEV%', db.name)-(PATINDEX ('%[_]%', db.name)+1)))
                    ELSE ''
              END) AS [DBName],

           -- Second Underscore
           PATINDEX ('%[_]DEV%', db.name) AS [Pos2], 

           -- System Name
           (CASE
              WHEN PATINDEX ('%[_]DEV%', db.name) > 0 THEN 'DEV'
              ELSE ''
            END)  AS [System_Name],

           -- System Name
           (CASE
              WHEN PATINDEX ('%[_]DEV-%', db.name) > 0 THEN PATINDEX ('%[_]DEV-%', db.name) + 4
              ELSE 0
            END)  AS [POS_3] 

            ---- Hyphen after 'DEV' System Name
         --  (CASE 
            --  WHEN db.name LIKE '%[_]DEV-%' THEN '-' 
            --  ELSE ''
            --END) AS [Hyphen]

           ---- Version Major
           --'' AS [VersionMajor],

           --'' AS [Dot1],

           ---- Version Minor
           --'' AS [VersionMinor],

           --'' AS [Dot2],

           ---- Revision 
           --'' AS [Revision],

           --'' AS [Dot3],

           ---- Build
           --'' AS [Build]

      FROM sys.databases db
      WHERE db.name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb')
  --UNION 
        --as above but with 3 digit Version
      --UNION 
        --as above but with 4 digit version

 )  X
WHERE 
    X.DBRealName != Concat(X.Client, X.US_1, X.DBName, X.US_2, X.System_Name)    --, X.Hyphen, X.VersionMajor, X.Dot1, X.VersionMinor, X.Dot2, X.Revision, X.Dot3, X.Build
```

Answer (score 0):

You could install a CLR regular expression function, then you can use proper regular expressions rather than the limited ones you get with PATINDEX?

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlclr/2005/06/29/working-with-regular-expressions/

Comment: I'll look into that James. Thanks.